# How to render a django-filter queryset to PDF?

Tags: django, django-filter

I am using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and I would like to add a button on my template to render as PDF after the user filtering the model.

Here my **views.py**

```
def search_people(request):
    person_list = models.Person.objects.all()
    person_filter = filters.PersonFilter(request.GET, queryset=person_list)

    return render(request, 'template.html', {
        'person_filter': person_filter,
        }
    )
```

How can the user filter the **Person** by **City** and render to PDF when he clicks on a button?

[This](https://codeburst.io/django-render-html-to-pdf-41a2b9c41d16/) as very helpful to render the entire **model** to PDF, but I only need the filtered part.

Comment: just assign the result of `render` to a variable (`html` for example), which will be the HTML of the page and then convert it to pdf.

Comment: How can I make this assignment? I also need to keep the actual return render(request, 'template.html', {'person_filter': person_filter,})